# How to use Flask-Moment with dynamically generated HTML?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, flask

I have API that generates table that uses Flask-Moment. API returns HTML code and then it's displayed on the page, but column that uses Flask-Moment is empty. I think it's somehow connected with the fact that Flask-Moment can't (probably) work with dynamically generated HTML.

So, how to use Flask-Moment with dynamically generated HTML?

[Table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYfvK.png)

**responses/submissions.html**:

```
<div class="submissions_table">
    <div class="table_header__wrapper">
        <div class="table_header">
            {# Result #}
            <div class="table_header_column result">
                <p>RESULT</p>
            </div>
            {# Language #}
            <div class="table_header_column language">
                <p>LANGUAGE</p>
            </div>
            {# Time #}
            <div class="table_header_column time">
                <p>TIME</p>
            </div>
            {# View result #}
            <div class="table_header_column view_result"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table_body">
        {% for submission in submissions %}
            <div class="table_row__wrapper">
                <div class="table_row">
                    {# Result #}
                    {% set submission_result = submission.get_result() %}

                    {% if submission_result['success'] %}
                        {% set result_status = 'success' %}
                    {% else %}
                        {% set result_status = 'fail' %}
                    {% endif %}

                    <div class="table_row_column result {{ result_status }}">
                        {# Status icon #}
                        {% if submission_result['success'] %}
                            <i class="result__icon far fa-check-circle"></i>
                        {% else %}
                            <i class="result__icon far fa-times-circle"></i>
                        {% endif %}
                        <p>{{ submission_result['message'] }}</p>
                    </div>
                    {# Language #}
                    <div class="table_row_column language">
                        {% set language_info = languages.get_info(submission.language) %}
                        <img src="{{ language_info['icon'] }}" alt="" class="language__icon">
                        <p class="language__name">{{ language_info['fullname'] }}</p>
                    </div>
                    {# Time #}
                    <div class="table_row_column time">{{ moment(submission.submission_date).fromNow() }}</div>
                    {# View result #}
                    <div class="table_row_column view_result">View Result</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share the code as text

Comment: @balderman Done. By the way, Flask-Moment is initialized in base.html ( {{ moment.include_moment() }} )

Comment: Do you follow https://flask-moment.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#rendering-timestamps-with-flask-moment ?